# Как посмотреть какие тестовые данные классифицируются неверно

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, keras, классификация, классификация-текста

Приветствую всех, есть вопрос касаемо нейронных сетей(библиотека keras).
Имеется модель, для классификации текста(хороший отзыв или плохой). Точность на выходе не 100%, значит есть тексты, которые  классифицируются сетью неверно. Как мне посмотреть на эти тексты после работы сети?

```
import numpy as np
import keras
from keras.datasets import imdb
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation,Dropout
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras import optimizers
from keras.layers import Conv1D, GlobalMaxPooling1D

np.random.seed(42)

max_features = 10000
maxlen = 400
batch_size = 64
embedding_dims = 200
filters = 150
kernel_size = 5
hidden_dims = 50
epochs =5

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = imdb.load_data(num_words=1000)

print(x_train.shape)
print(x_test.shape)
print(x_train[0])
print(y_train[0])
tokenizer = Tokenizer(num_words=1000)
x_train = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_train, mode='binary')
x_test = tokenizer.sequences_to_matrix(x_test, mode='binary')
print(x_train[0])

num_classes = 2
y_train = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_train, num_classes)
y_test = keras.utils.to_categorical(y_test, num_classes)
print(y_train.shape)
print(y_test.shape)

model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(512,input_dim = 1000,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(128,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(64,activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.2))
model.add(Dense(num_classes,activation='sigmoid'))
model.summary()



opt = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.1, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss="binary_crossentropy", optimizer=opt, metrics=['accuracy'])

clf = model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=128, epochs=5, validation_data=(x_test, y_test))

score = model.evaluate(x_test, y_test, verbose=1)
print("Accuracy: ", score[1])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как-то так ([идея позаимствована отсюда](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44891281/5741205)):

```
y_pred_vect = model.predict(x_test_vect)

# bolean mask
mask = (y_pred_vect != y_test_vect).any(axis=1)


num_words=1000 # only use top 1000 words
index_from=3   # word index offset

# этот шаг нужен чтобы получить `test_x` в изначальном виде (до токенизации):    
(train_x, _), (test_x, _) = imdb.load_data(num_words=num_words, index_from=index_from)
x_wrong = test_x[mask]

word_to_id = imdb.get_word_index()
word_to_id = {k:(v+index_from) for k,v in word_to_id.items()}
word_to_id["<PAD>"] = 0
word_to_id["<START>"] = 1
word_to_id["<UNK>"] = 2

id_to_word = {value:key for key,value in word_to_id.items()}
all_wrong_sents = [' '.join(id_to_word[id] for id in sent) for sent in x_wrong]
```

Результат:

```
In [119]: all_wrong_sents[:3]
Out[119]:
["<START> please give this one a miss br br <UNK> <UNK> and the rest of the cast <UNK> terrible performances the show is <UNK> <UNK> <UNK> br br i do
n't know how michael <UNK> could have <UNK> this one on his <UNK> he almost seemed to know this wasn't going to work out and his performance was quit
e <UNK> so all you <UNK> fans give this a miss",
 "<START> i <UNK> love this type of movie however this time i found myself <UNK> to <UNK> the screen since i can't do that i will just <UNK> about it
 this was absolutely <UNK> the things that happen with the dead kids are very cool but the <UNK> people are <UNK> <UNK> i am a <UNK> man pretty big a
nd i can <UNK> myself well however i would not do half the stuff the little girl does in this movie also the mother in this movie is <UNK> with her c
hildren to the point of <UNK> i wish i wasn't so <UNK> about her and her <UNK> because i would have otherwise enjoyed the flick what a number she was
 take my <UNK> and fast forward through everything you see her do until the end also is anyone else getting <UNK> of watching movies that are filmed
so dark <UNK> one can hardly see what is being filmed as an audience we are <UNK> involved with the <UNK> on the screen so then why the hell can't we
 have night <UNK>",
 '<START> the <UNK> richard <UNK> dog is <UNK> to <UNK> <UNK> <UNK> dog however when <UNK> <UNK> <UNK> <UNK> in town to <UNK> a <UNK> <UNK> to the <U
NK> his dog is <UNK> by <UNK> dog after a <UNK> <UNK> where <UNK> is <UNK> from town a <UNK> <UNK> that <UNK> dog must <UNK> dog so that she can <UNK
> her <UNK> <UNK> this is <UNK> and the <UNK> fall in love so do <UNK> and <UNK> the rest of the film <UNK> by with romance and at the end <UNK> dog
gives <UNK> but who is the father br br the dog story is the very weak <UNK> that is used to try and create a story between <UNK> its a terrible stor
yline there are 3 main musical <UNK> all of which are <UNK> bad songs and <UNK> <UNK> its just an extremely boring film <UNK> has too many words in e
ach <UNK> and <UNK> them in an almost <UNK> <UNK> its not funny ever but its meant to be <UNK> and <UNK> have done much better than this']
```

Comment: Комментарии не предназначены для расширенной дискуссии; разговор [перемещён в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75340/discussion-on-answer-by-maxu------).

Comment: Спасибо! А что за параметр UNK?

Comment: Хмм, кажется понял, сверил тексты из тестовой выборки и тем, что получилось на выходе, судя по всему, это слова, которые сеть не может идентифицировать, как-то так

Comment: А вы знакомы с tfc взвешиванием терминов?

Comment: К сожалению нет

Comment: Снова нужна ваша помощь, попробовал  новую модель с данными и на выходе получаю ошибку  x_wrong = test_x[mask]
IndexError: boolean index did not match indexed array along dimension 0; dimension is 25000 but corresponding boolean dimension is 7242

Comment: Не знаете как пофиксить?

Comment: @Midnight, попробуйте задать новый вопрос и привести в нем код для новой модели и текст ошибки

Comment: Посмотрите пожалуйста: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/808474/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%8B%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%B5-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8B

Comment: @MaxU, подскажите, после бесконечного числа попыток реализовать TFIDF взвешивание своими функциями, я решил использовать функцию TfidfVectorizer библиотеки sklearn. Но столкнулся с проблемой, что в параметрах векторайзера я указываю параметр max_features= int где int число первых слов из частотного словаря. И после векторизации мои массивы выборок меняют свои размеры. Т.е размерность вектора X_test была (25000,), а стала (25000, 10000) и теперь, функция которая выводит неправильные тексты выдает ошибку Data must be 1-dimensional

Comment: @MaxU Вот ошибка полностью `Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/NLP/CNN Network.py", line 501, in <module>
    mask = (y_pred_vect != y_test).any(axis=1)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\ops.py", line 857, in wrapper
    index=self.index).__finalize__(self)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 264, in __init__
    raise_cast_failure=True)
  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py", line 3275, in _sanitize_array
    raise Exception('Data must be 1-dimensional')
Exception: Data must be 1-dimensional`

Comment: @Midnight, попробуйте задать вопрос с [минимальным, самодостаточным и __воспроизводимым__ примером](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Comment: @MaxU Поправил функцию, но заметил, что тексты, которые выводятся постоянно одни и те же, тогда попытался вывести все тексты в файл, то он мне записал все 25000 документов, получается она выводит не неправильные тексты

Comment: Вот как исправил ошибку с размерностью mask = (np.squeeze(y_pred_vect) != y_test)

Comment: @MaxU не знаете в чем дело?

Comment: @Midnight, могу попробовать разобраться если выложите ваши данные ... Или вы работаете с imdb data set из Keras?

Comment: @MaxU ага, imdb сет

Comment: @Midnight, т.е. вы работаете не с текстами а с уже оцифрованными данными из `keras.datasets.imdb` ?

Comment: да, я использовал tfidf vectorizer

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76177/discussion-between-maxu-and-midnight).

Comment: @MaxU вопрос касаемо вашего метода, идея заключалась в том, чтобы вывести значения неравные y_test? Но получается, что все что предсказывает сеть - это значения от 0 до 1 с плавающей точкой и получается, что они все не равны y_test

Comment: @MaxU не знаете как можно поправить?

Comment: @Midnight, округлите до целого - получите нули и единицы.

Comment: Странно, значения  x_test после предсказания идут в разнобой, а когда вывожу y_test, то они упорядочены(сначала идут негативные, а потом позитивные) и поэтому так не получится их сравнить