# Как мне подать свой собственный текст на вход нейронной сети?

Tags: python, нейронные-сети, классификация-текста

Есть нейросеть, распознающая хороший отзыв о фильме или плохой. Как мне подать свой собственный текст на вход сети для проверки работоспособности?
Сама сеть:

```
 data = pd.concat([positive_train_data,negative_train_data,positive_test_data,negative_test_data],ignore_index = True)
    data.reset_index(drop=True,inplace=True)
    x = data.Text
    y = data.Sentiment

    x_train, x_test, y_train1, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = 0.50, random_state = 2000)
    print( "Train set has total {0} entries with {1:.2f}% negative, {2:.2f}% positive".format(len(x_train),
                                                                                 (len(x_train[y_train1 == 0]) / (len(x_train)*1.))*100,
                                                                                (len(x_train[y_train1 == 1]) / (len(x_train)*1.))*100))

    print ("Test set has total {0} entries with {1:.2f}% negative, {2:.2f}% positive".format(len(x_test),
                                                                                 (len(x_test[y_test == 0]) / (len(x_test)*1.))*100,
                                                                                (len(x_test[y_test == 1]) / (len(x_test)*1.))*100))

    tvec1 = TfidfVectorizer(max_features=10000,ngram_range=(1, 2),min_df=3,use_idf=1,smooth_idf=1,sublinear_tf=1,stop_words = 'english')
    tvec1.fit(x_train)
    x_train_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_train)
    print(x_test.shape)
    x_test_tfidf = tvec1.transform(x_test).toarray()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=10000))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimiz = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = optimiz ,metrics = ['accuracy'])
hist  = model.fit(x_train_tfidf,y_train1,validation_data = (x_test_tfidf,y_test ),epochs = 5,batch_size = 64)
```

Comment: Вы можете выложить ваши данные (или часть данных) так, чтобы можно было попробовать построить и протестировать модель?

Comment: @MaxU, под моими данными вы что подразумеваете? данные которыми я обучаю сеть? Это набор imdb http://ai.stanford.edu/~amaas/data/sentiment/. А на вход я хочу подать какое-нибудь простенькое предложение, для тестирования

Comment: Попробуйте привести в вопросе [минимальный, самодостаточный и __воспроизводимый__ пример](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5-%D1%8D%D1%84%D1%84%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81-%D0%BF%D0%BE-pandas-numpy-scipy-scikit-learn)

Comment: @MaxU залил сюда пример dropmefiles.com/k5mrK

Comment: @MaxU https://ru.files.fm/u/ggd6ebff#_ попробуйте отсюда

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/76179/discussion-between-maxu-and-midnight).

Answer (score 4):

Можно воспользоваться Keras для предварительной обработки текста:

```
from pathlib import Path
import pandas as pd
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Embedding, Dense, Dropout, Activation
from keras.preprocessing.text import Tokenizer, text_to_word_sequence
from keras import optimizers

def get_data(path):
    p = Path(path)
    train = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                       for f in p.glob('train_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    test = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep='\t', index_col=0)
                      for f in p.glob('test_???.tsv*')],
                      ignore_index=True)
    return ((train['Text'], train['Sentiment']),
           (test['Text'], test['Sentiment']))

# read data
(X_train, y_train), (X_test, y_test) = get_data(r'D:\download\NLP')

# build vocabulary
t = Tokenizer(num_words=10000)
t.fit_on_texts(X_train)
t.fit_on_texts(X_test)


# build a model
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu', input_dim=10000))
model.add(Dropout(0.25))
model.add(Dense(50,activation = 'relu'))
model.add(Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))
optimiz = optimizers.Adam(lr=0.0001, beta_1=0.9, beta_2=0.999, epsilon=1e-08, decay=0.0)
model.compile(loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = optimiz ,metrics = ['accuracy'])

# convert texts to TF-IDF matrices
X_train = t.texts_to_matrix(X_train, mode='tfidf')
X_test = t.texts_to_matrix(X_test, mode='tfidf')

# fit the model
hist = model.fit(X_train,y_train,validation_data = (X_test,y_test),epochs = 5,batch_size = 64)
```

Вывод:

```
Train on 25000 samples, validate on 25000 samples
Epoch 1/5
25000/25000 [==============================] - 12s 467us/step - loss: 0.4621 - acc: 0.7892 - val_loss: 0.3244 - val_acc: 0.8743
Epoch 2/5
25000/25000 [==============================] - 11s 434us/step - loss: 0.2319 - acc: 0.9153 - val_loss: 0.3020 - val_acc: 0.8821
Epoch 3/5
25000/25000 [==============================] - 11s 434us/step - loss: 0.1519 - acc: 0.9483 - val_loss: 0.3126 - val_acc: 0.8803
Epoch 4/5
25000/25000 [==============================] - 11s 435us/step - loss: 0.1023 - acc: 0.9674 - val_loss: 0.3463 - val_acc: 0.8776
Epoch 5/5
25000/25000 [==============================] - 11s 435us/step - loss: 0.0685 - acc: 0.9794 - val_loss: 0.3812 - val_acc: 0.8748
```

Проверяем модель на собственных текстах:

```
# predict our own texts
texts = ['what the hell is going on?', 'that was amazing', 'that was awful']
t.fit_on_texts(texts)
X = t.texts_to_matrix(texts, mode='tfidf')

model.predict(X)
```

Вывод:

```
Out[5]:
array([[0.47051138],
       [0.36511892],
       [0.24146256]], dtype=float32)
```

Comment: Спасибо, а как мне понять по этому  выводу `array([[0.47051138],
       [0.36511892],
       [0.24146256]], dtype=float32)` результат? ну т.е хороший отзыв или нет?

Comment: Но that was amazing всего 0.36511892, а должен быть чуть ли не 1

Comment: @Midnight, попробуйте задать эпох 10-20 - качество должно значительно улучшиться...

Comment: А вы пробовали вывести тексты, которые были определены сетью неверно?

Comment: Странно, уже после 2ой эпохи происходит переобучение, нет смысла увеличивать количество эпох...

Comment: Применив код отсюда, https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/807292/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D0%BA%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%80%D1%83%D1%8E%D1%82%D1%81%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%BE, получаю ошибку Data must be 1-dimensional на строке  mask = (y_pred_vect != y_test).any(axis=1)